# How to make multi column picker in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

I need to create a picker which have 2 columns in xamarin forms like timepicker. I am using Picker control. Is there any way through which we can make multiple columns in Picker?

Comment: Are there anything you tried? Please ask the complete question include anything you have done, any issue or something. 
Short answer: You can create custom control that looks like the Control you expect.

Comment: I tried to create the custom renderer for picker. but no idea how I can create two columns in a picker

Answer (score 2):

We've developed a two-column picker for Xamarin.Forms (Android and iOS).

Sample:
https://github.com/HorusSoftwareUY/MaterialDesignControlsPlugin#materialdoublepicker

Screenshots:
[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXaa7.png)
[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwGiN.png)

We added this control to MaterialDesignControls NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.MaterialDesignControls/), where you can find other interesting controls with the material design look and feel.

Contributions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Syncfusion Cascading control](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfpicker/cascading) for Xamarin, they are free if your company earn less than $1 million dollar in revenue.